# Some setting of Tmux doesnt work

Tags: tmux

On Mac Mountain lion, tmux installed via Homebrew.

Some settings like the following doesn't work:

```
setw -g pane-base-index 1
set -g mouse-resize-pane on
set -g mouse-select-pane on
set -g mouse-select-window on
```

Then error:

```
/Users/millisami/.tmux.conf: 52: unknown option: pane-base-index
/Users/millisami/.tmux.conf: 53: unknown option: mouse-resize-pane
/Users/millisami/.tmux.conf: 55: unknown option: mouse-select-window
```

Whats wrong?

Comment: if you use tmux 2.1, you can try [setw -g mode-mouse on](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33310514/2817245)

Answer (score 6):

As rado said, tmux 2.1 doesn't support the individual mouse settings. It replaced them with a single setting, `mouse` which can be set with `set -g mouse on` in your *~/.tmux.conf*.

As for the `pane-base-index` setting, Mark Nichols suggestion of:

```
# set window and pane index to 1 (0 by default)
set-option -g base-index 1
setw -g pane-base-index 1
```

worked for me on OS X 10.10.5 running tmux 2.1 installed via brew in iTerm 2.1.4.

Answer (score 2):

```
# set window and pane index to 1 (0 by default)
set-option -g base-index 1
setw -g pane-base-index 1

set -g mode-mouse on
setw -g mouse-select-window on
setw -g mouse-select-pane on
```

Comment: Can you post your entire .tmux.conf file?

Comment: This StackOverflow thread suggests that extra, invisible characters might be the issue: http://stackoverlfow.com/questions/12069477/tmux-tmux-conf-doesnt-load-properly. You might try opening the `.tmux.conf` file in Vim to see if there are invisible characters causing the issue.

Comment: Well I opened in Vim but I couldn't see any such chars. Is there any setting for Vim to see it?

Comment: I am getting the error for pane-base-index, couldn't find any invisible characters while opening .tmux.conf in vim. Also the correct link to the invisible character issue is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12069477/tmux-tmux-conf-doesnt-load-properly but that didn't help me with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that you are using tmux 2.1, which doesn't support those anymore.